# How to upload files from S3 to a signed url(generated using HTTP PUT in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have been trying to upload the file received from a S3 trigger to an externally generated signed url. The key code to upload the file using HTTP PUT is as follows

```
source_filename = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
with open(source_filename , 'r') as object_file:
    object_text = object_file.read()
response = requests.put(presigned_url, data=object_text)
```

the above method is recommended by [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-s3_basics-presigned_url.py.html)

This is not working since the open function is not able to recognize the "source_filename". Probably because open(a unix call) cannot recognize a S3 url(a custom file storage).

So what is the best method to upload  S3 files directly to  signed url

Comment: `source_filename` is an S3 object name?

Comment: It is the key or the exact filename

Answer (score 0):

> So what is the best method to upload S3 files directly to signed url

You can't upload directly from S3. You have to **download the S3 object** first, and then upload it using S3 pre-signed url to other destination.